Ansible defaults to /usr/bin/python and ignores env variables
Trying to use a python venv to run the play. The variable  ansible_python_interpreter seems to be ignored and the run defaults to /usr/bin/python
It's run from semaphore
Debug output from play:
ansible-playbook [core 2.17.5]
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/tmp/semaphore/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /tmp/semaphore/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.12.3 (main, Sep 11 2024, 14:17:37) [GCC 13.2.0] (/usr/bin/python3)
  jinja version = 3.1.2
 libyaml = True
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file

Playbook:
- name: testing keeper
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  environment:
    ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH: "/etc/ansible/roles"
    ANSIBLE_ACTION_PLUGINS: "/home/firmname/venv/ansible_venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keeper_secrets_manager_ansible/plugins/action_plugins"
    ANSIBLE_LOOKUP_PLUGINS: "/home/firmname/venv/ansible_venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keeper_secrets_manager_ansible/plugins/lookup_plugins"

  collections:
    - community.vmware
    - keepersecurity.keeper_secrets_manager

  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: "/home/firmname/venv/ansible_venv/bin/"

  tasks:
    - name: Load encrypted client config
      ansible.builtin.include_vars:
        file: "/home/incom/client-config.json"
      
    - name: Print the password cmetest
      keepersecurity.keeper_secrets_manager.keeper_get:
        command: get
        record_title: "VMLNXCMETEST01 (1)"
        field: "Password"
      register: cmetest_password

    - name: Print login name
      debug:
        var: cmetest_password.value
        verbosity: 0

I have tried changing the interpreter in ansible.cfg but the problem persist
/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg:
[defaults]
interpreter_python=/home/incom/venv/ansible_venv/bin/python3

Command run:
ansible-config dump --only-changed
CONFIG_FILE() = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
INTERPRETER_PYTHON(/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg) = /home/incom/venv/ansible_venv/bin/python3


This config is the path to Python used on the managed nodes, not on the controller.
